# I am not able to load tensorflow/serving in my docker container using windows powershell by using the following command

Tags: docker, tensorflow-serving

docker run -it -v C:\Users\HP\Documents\Deep Learning\potato_project:/potato_project -p 8605:8605 --entrypoint /bin/bash tensorflow/serving

It is showing docker:invalid reference format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAfIj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try your path into quotes:

docker run -it -v "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Deep Learning\potato_project:/potato_project" -p 8605:8605 --entrypoint /bin/bash tensorflow/serving

Its seems its due to the space in the path name